# Does Twilio chat support recording audio messages

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-chat, twilio-functions

We are using Twilio chat in one of our website and some users are asking if it is possible to record audio recordings to be sent as chat messages (like it happens on Whatsapp and other chatting App).

Does Twilio API support this kind of messages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

[Twilio Chat supports the upload and sharing of media](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/media-support) of all types to a maximum of 150MB size. You will need to implement the audio recording for your app, but once you've done that you can share over the chat platform.